# query all elements containing selected string symbolkeys from API

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, request

I am querying price data from an API, using the request.get function in python.
the query looks like:

```
requests.get(url_specified_contract, headers=headers, params={'SymbolKeys':'NDX GNM FMZ0022!'}).json()
```

where 'SymbolKeys' identifies the contract I look for.
Several contracts are traded for specific delivery periods, with a similar SymbolKey that varies only in the latter part. For instance:

```
'NDX GNM FMZ0022!'
'NDX GNM FMZ0023!'
'NDX GNM FMZ0024!'
....
```

Since the changing component could vary depending on the commodity I look at, I would like an easy way to get all ids containing a specified string (in my example 'NDX GNM'), without knowing which ones exist in advance.

I was trying queries like:

```
requests.get(url_quotes, headers=headers, params={'SymbolKeys':'*NDX GNM*'}).json()
```

Without success ({'Error': 'Unknown symbol(s): *NDX GNM*. This/these symbol(s) will not be part of the result.'}
).
The only solution for the time being is a for loop over each possible integer like:

```
quotes = []
for i in range(1,300):
    try:
        temp = requests.get(url_quotes, headers=headers, params={'SymbolKeys':'NDX GNM M'+str(i)}).json()

    except: pass    
    quotes.append(temp)
```

But this approach consumes a large amount of daily queries.
Could you suggest me a possible solution?
thanks in advance, cheers.

Comment: What API service are you using? There is probably some information about it in the reference.

Comment: I am using Montel API